# Flatten an Jobject with properties, and these properties have arrays

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this json string:

```
{
    "Id": "12345",
    "Clubs": {
    },
    "Hotel": {
        "OneStar": [
            {
                "id": "1-0",
                "SomeProperty": "blah"
            },
            {
                "id": "1-1",
                "SomeProperty": "blahX"
            }
        ],
        "TwoStar": [
            {
                "id": "2-0",
                "SomeProperty": ""
            }
        ],
        "ThreeStar": []
    }
}
```

I need to get a list with the children of hotel room details:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1-0",
        "SomeProperty": "blah"
    },
    {
        "id": "1-1",
        "SomeProperty": "blahX"
    },
    {
        "id": "2-0",
        "SomeProperty": ""
    }
]
```

The result array is just a list of strings, in order to achieve this I'm using nested foreach it seems not elegant and I guess is not performant; I'm sure that it should be a way to improve this by flattening the properties?

```
var roomDetails = new List<string>();
dynamic jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var room in jsonResponse.Hotel)
{
    foreach (var roomType in room)
    {
        foreach (var roomDetail in roomType)
        {
            roomDetails.Add(roomDetail.ToString());
        }
    }
}
return listOfRooms;
```

Comment: _"I guess is not performant"_ - why do you guess so? Also if you care about perfromance - do not use `dynamic`.

Comment: That's why I was guessing, due the dynamic xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that nested loops are just fine (or you can turn them into LINQ) but another approach can be using JSON path:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(...); // I would argue against using dynamic
var result = jObject.SelectTokens("$.Hotel.*[*]")
    // optionally - .OfType<JObject>()
    .Select(j => j.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

LINQ counterpart can be written in quite many ways, for this concrete structure you can use the following:

```
var ofType = ((JObject)jObject["Hotel"])
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Select(jo => jo.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Or:

```
var result = jObject["Hotel"]
    .Children<JProperty>()
    .Values<JArray>()
    .Values<JObject>()
    .Select(jo => jo.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Read more:

- [Newtonsoft Json.NET: Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)
- [JSON Path examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)
- [Newtonsoft Json.NET: Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm)